# How to pass parameters with LLVM

Tags: compiler-construction, llvm

I'm looking for ways by which I can extract static code features (like number of instructions) during compile time using LLVM and then store these values so that I can use during program execution.

Can this be done by TransformationPasses. I don't get this concept in LLVM documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to [write a pass](http://llvm.org/docs/WritingAnLLVMPass.html) that computes the information you need. You then need to inject that information into your module. A relatively straightforward way is to generate functions that, when called, return the computed values.

The programmer would then need to call these functions if she wants to receive these special values. The programmer will likely need to add the signatures herself, but your pass will replace the `declare` with an actual `define` which just returns a constant value. Those functions should also be annotated as inline.

You can also do this by replacing special variables or parameters or anything else, it's just that function calls seem to me as an elegant approach.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is too general. TransformationPasses transform your code (for instance dead code elimination). For analyzing there are Analysis passes. You can edit these passes to get what you need.

First, you can write your own analysis pass : http://llvm.org/docs/WritingAnLLVMPass.html . Second, you have functions like runOnFunction() (where you can use instruction iterators, or basic block iterators). For your particular example of counting instructions, just use a counter inside runOnFunction() or a LLVM method.

Comment: Yeah I get till there, but later part of question is, how can I use these values during program execution. Is there a way to pass these values

Comment: I assume "program execution" refers to the target program (on which you run the pass). when you run, first add the parameter created by you to identify your pass (-yourpass) and then the program itself. I think you want first the target program to be analyzed with your pass and then to actually run it, isn't it?

Comment: Exactly yes, writing a pass to analyse a program and then run the program itself

Comment: I can write a Analysis pass to obtain values and then use a Transformation Pass to instrument the source code with this obtained value

Comment: Therefore, there is not "during program execution". There are two different steps. First, run your pass over target program: //home/.../llvm/Release+Asserts/bin/opt -load //home/.../llvm/Release+Asserts/lib/YOURS.so -your_pass_param //home/.../llvm/.../Target program.bc  Second, you can use your results wherever you want.